# jquery ajax html response... changing input value is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Experts,

I am having a hard time getting jquery to modify some HTML values that is dynamically injected via an ajax response.

https://jsfiddle.net/ksa0yg9y/

I have some html on page:

```
<button id="test">test</button>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Script (simulating the html response by setting the html as static value):

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(){
    $.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: '/echo/html/',
  success:
  function(data) {
        $('.main').html('<input id="txt" type="text" name="title" value="">');
      }
  });
    $('#txt').val('test');
});
```

Expected result would be for the

But as you can see from the jsfiddle, the input value remains blank.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Both below answers are correct, but NullDev explains why and gives a demo. Here is [your jsFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/ksa0yg9y/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call which Ajax performs is asynchron. You need to "wait" until the data is actually there. 
Try to use a callback:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.main').html('<input id="txt" type="text" name="title" value="">');
            callback();
        }
    });
    function callback() {
        $('#txt').val('test');
        //...
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uk2b0k3a/)**</kbd>

Comment: when using static data for html this works fine... when actually waiting on the ajax response (non simulated) it is not... i think you may be right that its not detecting the html response and attempting to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.main').html('<input id="txt" type="text" name="title" value="">');
            $('#txt').val('test');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: not working... i think the problem is that the .html(response) is not loading fast enough for the value to be set.

Comment: That's interesting cuz when I tried it it worked....

Comment: This kind of patch work is hardly reliabl. Sometimes they work, mostly they they fail.